# Expectation of Exponential Variable conditional on sum of this and another Exponential Variable

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I would like to find

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[ q | q + v = k] \\
\mbox{where} \quad q \sim \mbox{exp}(\lambda) \\
\mbox{and} \quad v \sim \mbox{exp}(\mu) \\
\mbox{and} \quad k = \mbox{some constant}
\end{align*}

I have tried the following approach:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[ q | q + v = k] = \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{f_{q \cap (q + v)}(q)}{f_{q+v}(k)} \mbox{d}q
\end{align*}

For which I have already found the convolution density of $f_{q+v}$ but I don't know how to find the density $f_{q\cap(q+v)}$. 
Moreover, I am unsure if this approach is correct and / or efficient in general.

In addition to answer suggestions, I would greatly appreciate if someone could reference a textbook that deals well with issues such as this.